# AWS cognito registration and login - how to store pool and app id

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using this example to setup a registration/login UI with an *AWS Cognito* user pool: https://medium.com/@gmonne/custom-authentication-using-aws-cognito-e0b489badc3f

The author suggests keeping the user pool and application IDs private by creating a config.js file that saves this information in two global variables.  From the `readme.md`:

> Before running this code you should create a JavaScript file inside the `javascript` folder called `config.js`. Here you should set your "User Pool" id and app client id on the window object using the names: `USER_POOL_ID`, and `CLIENT_ID`.

I set the variables in config.js as follows, but get a `USER_POOL_ID is not defined` error.

```
var USER_POOL_ID: "us-east-1_#######";
var APP_CLIENT_ID: "7pcmh9gre807########";
```

From the cognito.js file in the example:

```
(function(win, CognitoUserPool) {

var CognitoUserPool = window.AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool,
AWSCognito = window.AWSCognito,
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider,CognitoUserAttribute = CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute,
CognitoUser = CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser,
AuthenticationDetails = CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails,
UserPool = new CognitoUserPool({
UserPoolId : window.USER_POOL_ID, // Your user pool id here
ClientId : window.CLIENT_ID, // Your client id here
```

What is the syntax to set the IDs on the window object as mentioned in the readme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are set using `=` not `:`, so change `config.js`:

```
var USER_POOL_ID = "us-east-1_#######";
var APP_CLIENT_ID = "7pcmh9gre807########";
```

It's not clear how this file is being used but if you wanted to set the window object directly, you would do

```
window.USER_POOL_ID = "us-east-1_#######";
window.APP_CLIENT_ID = "7pcmh9gre807########";
```

And the cognito.js code isn't using the correct variable name, it has no `APP_` prefix, so change the last line to:

```
ClientId : window.APP_CLIENT_ID, // Your client id here
```